# Convert from String of ByteArray to String

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I am trying to convert string to UTF-8 and store it in shared preferences but after getting its value I can't convert string which contains byte array to string

```
var myString ="hello world"
var bytes :ByteArray = myString.toUtf8Bytes()    

value of Bytes // [104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 109, 121, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]

var result :String =   bytes.contentToString()

value of result // "[104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 109, 121, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]"
```

How can I get the value of myString from the result?

thanks in advance

Comment: Experimental, but see https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/decode-to-string.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert byte array to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950019/convert-byte-array-to-string)

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950019/convert-byte-array-to-string

Comment: all this methods use bytearray as input , i want to use string of bytearray as input and get result string

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String(byteArray)` to convert `ByteArray` to 'String' in kotlin

```
    val str = "hello world."
    val byte = str.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
    val newStr = String(byte)
    assert(str == newStr)
```

Comment: Note: it will use the platform's default charset, which may not be UTF-8.

Comment: let say we have byte variable as String contains the value how you can get str in this case

Comment: i have byteArray in String variable and i want to get its actual string Value

Comment: for encode any byteArray to String and decode. you can use binary-to-text encoding algorithms like 
Base64, ASCII85 or etc...

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer here , error was in the way in storing data in shared Preferences and way to get it from string:

[Storing ByteArray in sharedPreferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556433/saving-byte-array-using-sharedpreferences)